# How to interpolate data using basemap?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have been trying for a long time now to make this simple basemap work. However, there is something with the format of the data basemap expects, which I cannot figure out. Can anybody help me understand what am I doing wrong?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import meshgrid
import numpy as np

lats  = [-17.96, -2.88, -3.12, -14.01, -9.28, -15.59, -15.69]
longs = [-38.69, -40.13, -40.04, -52.21, -37.89, -47.62, -41.43]
prod  = [ 24.6, 7.5, 8.5, 68.8, 6.8, 6.6, 31.0]

lats = np.asarray(lats)
longs = np.asarray(longs)
prod = np.asarray(prod)

map = Basemap(projection='tmerc',
          lat_0=0, lon_0=3,
          llcrnrlon=1.819757266426611,
          llcrnrlat=41.583851612359275,
          urcrnrlon=1.841589961763497,
          urcrnrlat=41.598674173123)

x = linspace(0, map.urcrnrx, prod.shape[1])
y = linspace(0, map.urcrnry, prod.shape[0])

xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)

map.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the result when you run that?  Errors, unexpected output, no output at all?

Comment: @Midavalo: ... line 23 ...  x = linspace(0, map.urcrnrx, prod.shape[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant info including the errors. Don't just add as comment

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the libraries, but I'm curious what you get if you add print(prod.shape[1]) in line 22. You may have issues if it is not a [non-negative integer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Comment: Better yet, print(0, map.urcrnrx, prod.shape[1]) and see if you get two scalars and an integer. I suspect you may get two scalars and a tuple and need something like prod.shape[1][0] for the third argument. If you get an error, perhaps try print(prod.shape) and see if you have two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `prod` is a one dimensional array, so it's `shape` attribute has a length of one. Thus `prod.shape[0]` works, but `prod.shape[1]` raises an index error. While I don't have a clue of what `prod` represents, it is probably suppose to be a 2D array of data that is mapped in the matrix.

Perhaps you can represent the size of `x` and `y` dimensions using the lengths of `lats` and `longs`:

```
x = linspace(0, map.urcrnrx, len(longs))
y = linspace(0, map.urcrnry, len(lats))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
x = linspace(0, map.urcrnrx, prod.shape[0])
```

in line 23. The prod array has 7 items that match both the 7 lats and 7 longs. It isn't a two-dimensional array, so

```
prod.shape
```

returns the tuple (7L,) as a long integer inside a single-item tuple. Your code gives an index out of range because there is only one value in the tuple at index 0 and no value for index of 1. Using prod.shape[0] will return the integer 7, and I presume it is appropriate in your code to use this value for both line 23 and 24.

see [linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and [shape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html)